# Get Width Of First Cell In First Column In GridView

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET GridView. I am trying to find out how one can read and set the width of the first cell, in the first column in jQuery.

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...how one can read and set the width of the first cell, in the first column

If you mean the first cell in the first **row**, then it's a selector combined with the `:first` pseudo-selector or the `.first` method:

```
var width = $("selector-for-the-cell:first").width();
```

or

```
var width = $("selector-for-the-cell").first().width();
```

The second is preferred because it allows jQuery to offload the initial selection to the browser's built-in handling.

Gratuitous live example:

```js
$("input[type=button]").on("click", function() {
  alert($("td").first().width());
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>First cell</td>
      <td>Second cell</td>
      <td>Third cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Click me">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```